# Change/Map levels of a data frame columns using other reference list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to change levels of the data frame and convert them to appropriate type using reference list.

**Sample Data:**

```
dt <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c(50,10,20,30,99,190),c=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))
ref_list <- list(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=NULL,c=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))

str(dt)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ b: num  50 10 20 30 99 190
 $ c: Factor w/ 6 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**Desired Output:**

convert it to `numeric`, if it is `NULL` in the `ref_list` else convert it to `factor` with levels found in the `ref_list`

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ b: num  50 10 20 30 99 190
 $ c: Factor w/ 6 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this, first identifying the variables that need converting, i.e., the variables that are not `NULL` in the list and also appear in the data frame, then converting in a quick for loop.

```
vars_to_convert = intersect(names(ref_list)[lengths(ref_list) > 0], names(dt))

for (var in vars_to_convert) {
  dt[[var]] = factor(dt[[var]], levels = ref_list[[var]])
}

str(dt)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  $ b: num  50 10 20 30 99 190
#  $ c: Factor w/ 6 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```